# How to test a private method in Java when testing through public API is ugly?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I have a Java program which reads user commands from the terminal (until he types `exit`) and performs some computation.

The code looks as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String command = read_from_stdin();
    while (!command.equals("exit")) {
        String output = execute(command)
        System.out.println(output);
        command = read_from_stdin();
    }
}

private String execute(String command) {...}
```

The question is: how do I test the private `execute` method?

1. Test through the public `main` function. That requires to feed the input into the main program not from the terminal but from some file. Probably this test will be not a Java Unit test, rather some shell script. YUCK.
2. Make execute `public` and write Java test for it. Doesn't this break the idea of using `private/public` access modifiers?

Any other ideas?

**UPDATE**

Several comments suggest to refactor `execute` into a separate class. So if I do something like this:

```
class Executor {
    public String execute(String command) {...}
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Executor executor = new Executor();
        String command = read_from_stdin();
        while (!command.equals("exit")) {
            String output = executor.execute(command);
            System.out.println(output);
            command = read_from_stdin();
        }
    }
}
```

Then sure, I can now Unit-test the public `Executor` api. But isn't this conceptually the same as making `execute` public (and if not the same, then why is this better)?

Comment: @xerx, my mistake, updated

Comment: If you do not want to make your method _public_, you can also make it _package private_ (i.e. without any modifier) and have a test class in the same package that can access this method. But others can not.

Comment: Wanting to make a private method public for testing is often (but not always) a signal that there is a new class waiting to be born. In your original code, Main is responsible for two things: I/O and execute, this can also be a signal that a new class is trying to get out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes you dont want to go the extra mile of extracting everything out. Sometimes you cannot go for best practices for various reasons.

A good solution to this problem is to make the method package private (remove private). If your test is in the same package, then you can access that method and test it directly.

I would personally also add @VisibleForTesting to make clear that this method is accessible because of testing reasons.

In general this is sometimes which is rarely done and always points to some wrong designs.

Answer (score 3):

You are not supposed to test private methods, it's like you аре testing that something is implemented in a concrete way, instead of testing functionality. If you need to test something private, then there is good chance it should have been public in the first place. Looking at your example, this looks like the case to me.

I would refactor the code, before starting tests.

1. Make an executor for each command. Now you can test each executor separately for correct handling of the command.
2. Make some kind of dispatcher/strategy/factory, which instantiates the correct executor for the command. You can now test the logic, if the correct executor has been chosen.

**Edit:** To address your additional question, this is **not** conceptually the same as simply changing the access modifier. This approach splits the responsibilities into independent from each other units. Currently your main class has at least 3 responsibilities - input/output, choosing correct logic to execute depending on command and executing said logic. This violates the single responsibility principle from [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID):

> There should never be more than one reason for a class to change. In other words, every class should have only one responsibility.

This approach is better because it will make the code adhere more to the principles of writing easily extensible and easily maintainable code.

Comment: So, essentially, make "execute" method public, only in a clever way, by introducing new classes?

Comment: OK, makes sense, I accepted the answer. One question thought, what would be an example of a private method, that should not be refactored into a separate class, but which could nevertheless be tested through a public API?

Comment: @mercury0114 Basically a method, whose only purpose is to give name to certain action/s. An extremely simplified example would be a method, which receives input and writes it let's say to OutputStream1 and OutputStream2.

Answer (score 0):

Usual practice is to extract method in separate class and test that class.

Comment: Doesn't this essentially make the private method public, only in a fancy way? And maybe that's not a bad idea after-all?

Comment: Yes it does, but as long you keep reference to that class private it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Although if the method is static (and it should be static in the case it doesn't modify the state), then the private method becomes public.